# Storing shuffled arrays in a parrent array

Tags: javascript, arrays, v8

### Problem : Main array have identical arrays instead of shuffle arrays after shuffling

```js
// Initiating an empty array
const mainArr = []

// Random array with any values 
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// Function to shuffle array
let shuffleArray = (arr) => {
    let newPos, temp
    arr.forEach((_, indx) => {
        newPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
        temp = arr[newPos]
        arr[newPos] = arr[indx]
        arr[indx] = temp
    })
    return arr
}

// Looping 5 times to generate shuffled arrays
for(let i = 1; i<=5; i++){

  // Pushing shuffled array to mainArr
  mainArr.push(shuffleArray(arr))
}

console.log(mainArr)
```

- I tried to shuffle an array 5 times and store it in another array ie. 'mainArr'
- Created a function that accepts an array as argument and return shuffled array
- I looped it 5 times , Called the function and passed an array as arg. Then pushed the result of the function in mainArr
- After loop got over , mainArr shows 5 identical arrays instead of shuffled array

Please help...

Comment: Besides `mainArray`, you only have 1 array, not 5. The last shuffle affects that single array, which you have put 5 times in the main array.

Comment: `mainArr.push(shuffleArray(arr))` pushes the shuffled array into `mainArr`. I guess you're trying to shuffle it 5 times in the `for` loop, after the loop `push` once.